# Tikz - drawing parallel lines that truncate at the same x-coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

Currently I have a figure that looks like this : 
[image]

However, I want the parallel lines to be "truncated" at the horizontal line. The lengths of all the parallel lines are equal, and an irrational number, and so are the coordinates of the end points, if they are truncated on the horizontal line. Hence, to draw them, I do not wish to either utilize the length of the line, or the coordinates of the end points of the lines on the horizontal line. (The slopes of all the lines are 1)

How can I do this?

Here is the code I used to draw them:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!50,
                    inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]
\draw {(0,0)  -- (5,-5)node{}}; 
\draw \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}
 {
  (\x,-\x) node{} -- (-5+\x,-5-\x) 
 };
\draw {(-5,-5) -- (5,-5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I think you can use the `intersection` library or the `clip` facility....

Answer (score 1):

A elementary solution: recalculating length of lines and use polar coordinates ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!50,
                    inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]
\draw {(0,0)  -- (5,-5)node{}};
\draw \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}
 {
  (\x,-\x) node{} -- + (225:{1.414*(5-\x)}) % <--- 
 };
\draw {(-5,-5) -- (5,-5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Clip the area above (or below) the line.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, draw, fill=black!50,
                    inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8]

\begin{scope}
\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,0.2);
\draw {(0,0)  -- (5,-5)node{}}; 
\draw \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}
 {
  (\x,-\x) node{} -- (-5+\x,-5-\x) 
 };
\draw {(-5,-5) -- (5,-5)};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, clip seems to work the best. You don't have to deal with the irrational lengths of the lines, or their irrational end points on the horizontal.

Comment: @Chameleon Yes, the problem is that you need to know where to clip.